# Overwrite columns while joining dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I needed to shift values over to the left if there were NA's present on the left. To do this, I subsetted my dataframe combine1, creating combine2 and applied the following function:

```
combine2 <- combine1 %>%
  select(ID, Col3:Col7)
combine2[] <-  t(apply(combine2, 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
```

I am trying to join the two back together, keeping the shifted values from combine 2, or overwriting them over the combine1 values. I have been looking through dplyr join function, but I can't seem to find anything to make this work. Is there a way to join these two together, or possibly a way to apply that NA shifting function within the original dataframe without having to subset it out first?

This is the result of the NA shifting function:

```
combine1
# A tibble: 6 x 9
     ID Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>
1     1 text  text  P12-1 P14-5 NA    NA    NA    text 
2     2 text  text  P98-2 NA    P65-7 NA    NA    text 
3     3 text  text  NA    P53-1 NA    NA    NA    text 
4     4 text  text  P77-8 NA    NA    NA    NA    text 
5     5 text  text  NA    P58-1 P11-0 NA    NA    text 
6     6 text  text  NA    NA    P34-5 NA    NA    text
```

```
combine2
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ID    Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 1     P12-1 P14-5 NA    NA    NA   
2 2     P98-2 P65-7 NA    NA    NA   
3 3     P53-1 NA    NA    NA    NA   
4 4     P77-8 NA    NA    NA    NA   
5 5     P58-1 P11-0 NA    NA    NA   
6 6     P34-5 NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Here is dput() from the dataframe:

````
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Col1 = c("text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text"), Col2 = c("text", "text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text"), Col3 = c("P12-1", "P98-2", NA, "P77-8", 
NA, NA), Col4 = c("P14-5", NA, "P53-1", NA, "P58-1", NA), Col5 = c(NA, 
"P65-7", NA, NA, "P11-0", "P34-5"), Col6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Col7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Col8 = c("text", "text", 
"text", "text", "text", "text")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Col1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Col2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Col3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Col4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Col5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Col6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), Col7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), Col8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))```
````

Comment: You can do it in a single step:  `combine1[paste0("Col", 3:7)] <- t(apply(combine1[paste0("Col", 3:7)], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))`

Comment: It works in this example, but doesn't seem to be working for my actual data set. In the actual data set the values aren't numbers, but are a combination of letters and numbers, like P123, P487, etc. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Another possibility that isn't included is that there can be multiple NA's before a good value. I'll update the question to match the data set better.

Comment: Updated the example. Even with the changes, it still works, but unfortunately doesn't work on my real data set.

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean?  An error? Gives the wrong result? More detail would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry. There weren't any errors, but looking through, it seems that the t(apply(combine1[paste0("Col", 3:7)], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))) portion is failing to shift over values on my actual data set. It works fine with the provided example, but isn't functioning properly with my actual data.

Comment: Starting with the obvious, did you change `paste0("Col", 3:7)` (on both the left hand and right hand side) so the appropriate columns are being indexed?

Comment: Yes. With the actual data frame, it looks like this: ```df[paste0("column", 1:10)] <- t(apply(df[paste0("column", 1:10)], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))```

Comment: Check that the `NA` values are actually `NA` and not character strings / factors masquerading as `NA`.  If it's not that you'll need to post some example data where the issue is reproduced.

Comment: That was it!!!! That would have driven me insane. If you put your initial reply up as a solution I'll check it as solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code you provided, you can replace the data in a single step by indexing the left hand side:

```
combine1[paste0("Col", 3:7)] <- t(apply(combine1[paste0("Col", 3:7)], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)])))
```

Comment: @H 1, I just updated my packages and found that this solution isn't functioning any longer. Instead of shifting values over to the left, it now just repeats the first value found in each row out for the rest of the columns afterwards.

Comment: You can try to wrap it in `data.frame()` - `data.frame(t(apply(combine1[paste0("Col", 3:7)], 1, function(x) c(x[!is.na(x)], x[is.na(x)]))))`.

Comment: @Corey - note that this was caused by a behavior change in `tibble 3.0.0` that has been reverted in `3.0.1` so the original answer should work again if you update the package. See https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/762